# How can I synchronize two audio recordings *without* timestamps?

Tags: audio, synchronization

Let's say I have two separate recordings of the same concert (created on a user's phone and then uploaded to our server). These recordings are then aligned according to their creation timestamp. However, when these recordings are played together or quickly toggled between, it is revealed that their creation timestamps must be off because there is a perceptible delay.

Since the time stamp is not a reliable way to align these recordings, what is an alternative? I would really prefer not to have to learn about audio signal processing to solve this problem, but recognize this may be the only way. So, I guess my question is:

1. Can I get away with doing some kind of clock synchronization? Is that even possible if the internal device clocks are clearly off by an unknown amount? If yes, a general outline of how this would work and key words would be appreciated.
2. If #1 is not an option, I guess I need to learn about audio signal processing? Again, a general outline of how to tackle the problem from that angle and some key words would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 separate issues you need to deal with. Issue 1 is the alignment of the start time of the recordings. I doubt you can expect that both user's pressed record at the exact same moment. Even if they did they may be located different distances from the speaker and it takes time for sound to travel. Aligning the start times by hand is pretty trivial. The human brain is good at comparing the similarities of sound. Programmatically it's a different story. You might try using something like cross correlation or looking over on dsp.stackexchange.com. There is no exact method though.

Issue 2 is that the clocks driving the A/D converters on the two devices are not going to be running at the same exact rate. So even if you synchronize the start time, eventually the two are going to drift apart. The time it takes to noticeably drift is a function of the difference of the two clock frequencies. If they are relatively close you may not notice in a short recording. To counter act this you need to stretch the time of one of the recordings. This increases or decreases the duration of the recording without affecting the pitch. There are plenty of audio recording apps that allow you to time stretch but they don't give you any help in figuring out by how much. Start be googling "time stretching" or again have a look at dsp.stackexchange.com.

I realize neither of these are direct answers - rather suggestions.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I should have specified what I meant by "align". I did not mean simply have them start at the same time regardless of timestamp. I meant that if one recording started earlier than the other, then cut off the the beginning part of the first so that they both start at the same time, at least according to their timestamps. The problem is that these are clearly not actually the same time (unless the "time stretching" issue is what is causing the problem. They are short clips though, so I am not sure. I will need to test if the problem gets measurably worse as it plays on.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://www.sonicvisualiser.org/doc/tutorial/en/sv-alignment.pdf) document, describes how you can align recordings using Sonic Visualizer(GPL) and a plugin.

I've not used it before, but found the document (and this question) when I was faced with a similar problem.

Comment: Fyi -- that same example ("February 2009: Audio alignment using Sonic Visualiser and MATCH") is included in their (Sonic Visualizer) list of examples ( http://www.sonicvisualiser.org/videos.html )  with link to video ( https://vimeo.com/3310893 ). The link to the pdf is also still working (10/2017).